# Window wide background combined with a div limited in width

Tags: css, html

I would like to try to build a clean and nice piece of code where I can accomplish the result you see in the image below. It's ok in Firefox, Chrome or Safari, but not in IE.

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ljgg/) with the code.
Basically all I want a 100% width of the red bar (edge to edge in the window) but the content (including the navigation) should be limited in width.
So I'm looking for a nice, clean snippet to make this work in all browsers (including IE...)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
 body{
   background-color: #fff;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 #subtopContainer{
   background-color: #f00;
 }
 #subtop, #header, #content{
   width: 980px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
 }
 #header{
   height: 150px;
 }
 #subtop{
   height: 50px;
 }
</style>

<div id='container'>
 <div id='headerContainer'>
   <div id='header'></div>
 </div>
 <div id='subtopContainer'>
   <div id='subtop'></div>
 </div>
 <div id='contentContainer'>
   <div id='content'></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
   body { background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
   div.wrapper { margin: 0 auto; width: 980px; background: lime}
   div.header { height: 70px; margin-bottom: 40px;}
   div.content { height: 400px; }
   div.bar { height: 40px; background: #f00; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 70px; width: 100%;}
 </style>

<body>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      Header Stuff
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      In order for this to work, 

      div.bar 'top' = div.header 'height' 
      div.header 'margin-bottom' = div.bar 'height'.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```